# Vim colors not behaving how I expect?

Tags: vim, colors

I read [this article](https://dev.to/huytd/turning-off-the-syntax-highlighter-8af) on turning off syntax highlighting, and I wanted to try the "color" scheme the author uses (effectively all white with some bolded words and a yellowish cursor), which he [links to here](https://gist.github.com/huytd/8394f21bda3a08be025813c060d64e75). However, when I try to apply it in my terminal, it ends up looking like this instead:

[image: Definitely not the intended color scheme]

What could be causing that? Context:

- macOS 10.13.2
- Terminal 2.8 (xterm-256color)
- The color file exactly as it appears in the second link is in ~/.vim/colors/
- My .vimrc:

  ```
  set nocompatible
  syntax on
  set formatoptions=tcroql
  set relativenumber
  set incsearch
  set hlsearch
  set smartindent
  filetype indent on
  let g:go_highlight_trailing_whitespace_error=0
  ```

Comment: Don't you want to turn your `syntax off` in the .vimrc? Thanks for sharing the article in any event. I thought about it for just a moment and decided to turn my syntax highlighting off.

Comment: Turning it off completely just makes it completely white and plain, but the bolded keywords and colored cursor seem like a nice touch that I want.

Comment: That is subtle. I'm installing and seeing if I can get this to work. So far, I've probably had worse luck than you. You've installed the base16-shell as the other comment has suggested?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried installing and configuring it, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments in [the color schema](https://gist.github.com/huytd/8394f21bda3a08be025813c060d64e75) I see you need to install and configure [base16-shell](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-shell).

Set this variable in your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:base16_shell_path=base16-builder/output/shell/
```

before running `:color`. Set the actual path where you install the scripts.

Comment: I noticed that, and I hadn't installed it, but I have now and it still hasn't made a difference.